# Que tipo de variável aloca menos memória, integer ou string?

Tags: string, delphi, tipagem, memória, int

Imaginando a situação que estou pegando do banco de dados um campo número, que representa o código do cliente.

Este valor tende a ser entre 1 até 50000. Devo para este caso salvar como `string` ou como `integer` para alocar menos memória?

Exemplos:

Modo 1:

```
procedure TFrmCadCliente.Teste(Sender: TObject);
var
  vCodCliente : integer;
begin
  vCodCliente := cdsClienteCodCliente.AsInteger;
end;
```

Modo 2:

```
procedure TFrmCadCliente.Teste(Sender: TObject);
var
  vCodCliente : string;
begin
  vCodCliente := cdsClienteCodCliente.AsString;
end;
```

Sei que, se for utilizar o código como inteiro deverei então converter e neste caso é melhor salvar diretamente como `integer`, mas, para meu caso em especifico isto não será necessário.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Que tipo de fruta cabe mais unidades de dentro de uma caixa de mesmo tamanho, uva ou melancia? Mesmo sabendo qual é, de que adianta se você gosta de melancia?

Você deve usar tipos numéricos para representar números, algo que depende de cálculos, que represente quantidades de alguma coisa (data, valor de estoque, preço, etc.). E deve usar texto para representar descrições, mesmo que essas descrições possuam apenas caracteres numéricos (telefone, CPF, etc.).

Pelo que está falando é algo contável (não precisa fazer conta, basta ser uma quantidade) e deve ser `integer`.

Mas se quer saber mesmo qual ocupa mais espaço é a `string`. Um tipo `integer` ocupará 4 bytes e é por valor, então o valor já está no objeto em si. Uma `string` é um tipo por referência, então já ocupará 4 ou 8 bytes (se é 32 ou 64 bytes) só para representar o ponteiro para o objeto real. E aí no objeto real ocupará no mínimo 4 bytes (na verdade é quase certo que seja bem mais, não conheço os detalhes de implementação do Delphi para esse tipo).

Haverá 4 bytes porque eu sei que esse tipo tem seu tempo de vida controlado por um contador de referências que precisa de pelo menos 4 bytes, talvez 8 bytes. Estou considerando que uma *string* vazia tenha alguma otimização, mas é improvável. Provavelmente tem mais 1 à 8 bytes (sempre dependendo da arquitetura que está rodando e o tipo *string*  específico) para indicar o tamanho dessa *string* (na verdade pode ser que limite em 4 por decisão dos implementadores). E pode ser que tenha mais algum outro metadado, como por exemplo um ponteiro para o tipo para indicar polimorfismo, mas talvez não precise em `string` por ser uma classe que não pode ser herdada, porém ela herda, então pode precisar sim.

E aí terá pelo menos mais 1 byte para cada caractere, nesse caso se for o texto `50000`, serão 5 bytes nas implementações padrões.

Como não sei a implementação real do Delphi pode ser que ainda tenha mais um caractere de terminador (`\0`). E poderá ser que tenha mais de 1 byte por caractere, dependendo da codificação (eu sei que o Delphi tem várias , mas não sei como é a padrão). E poderá haver otimizações para guardar o tamanho da *string*.

Isso tudo no Delphi, já no banco de dados é diferente, mas a ideia básica é a mesma, o texto tem 1 byte (ou 2 ou 4) por caractere e o inteiro tem 4 bytes (depende um pouco da tecnologia).

De qualquer forma, `integer` é bem menor e mais simples, e dá menos problema, é mais performático por várias razões.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que colocou que eu queria entender.

Answer (score 5):

No delphi existem vários [tipos de inteiro](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Integer_Types), cada um ocupando determinada quantidade de memória e com determinado intervalo de valores possíveis. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu exemplo poderia utilizar um tipo WORD, que ocuparia apenas 16bits de memória e tem capacidade de armazenar valores de 0 a 65535.

Já os [tipos String](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/String_Types_(Delphi)) ocupam espaço variável em memória, dependendo do tamanho da string
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo utilizando strings o tamanho ocupado na memória é variável conforme o tamanho do número.

Agora numa questão de boa prática de programação, se o valor é um numero, deve ser armazenado como numero, o código ficará mais legível e fácil de fazer manutenções futuras, evitando várias conversões desnecessárias que só aumentará o processamento da sua aplicação.